# Pipeline file name in Multibranch jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way or a variable which I can use to access the name of the Pipeline script file which has been defined in the multibranch Jenkins job. I have a project with the same pipeline code but named different in different projects. So for instance it is called Jenkinsfile in one project while Pipeline-script in another. So need a way in which I can find the name of this file from within the Pipeline job.

Comment: If you have Jenkinsfile with different names, you can specify it in Configure section for the project and say JenkinsfileA, JenkinsfileB in the same order.
That implies, for a given repository, Jenkins looks to find JenkinsfileA and if that is not found JenkinsfileB and so on.

Comment: Thats not what my question intends. I want to find the name of the Pipeline script from within a jenkins shared library.